# Understanding the use of the imperfect subjunctive

Tags: subjonctif, imparfait

From what I've been told the imperfect subjunctive is not used commonly in either spoken or written French so I'm assuming that when it's used, there is a very specific reason. So my question is why is the imperfect subjunctive used in this quote from L'Étranger (which is the first time I noticed it in the novel and this is right at the very end): « C'était assez drôle que je ne m'en fusse pas avisé plus tôt »?

For context the « en » refers to how Meursault never realised that guillotines were small and that people didn't need to climb a scaffold to get executed.

Comment: L'imparfait du subjonctif est utilisé (plutôt rarement de nos jours) surtout dans un contexte soutenu, comme ici ou Albert Camus rapproche le présent de la vision/perception immédiate de la guillotine à l'image qu'il en a gardé au contact des illustrations historiques de la Révolution française, période révolue où le subjonctif était plus souvent employé par les lettrés.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the this tense was not that much driven by a grammatical requirement but was probably more kind of an intellectual exercise, perhaps just to entertain the reader. It's something you can afford to do when you're a great writer, otherwise you risk being ridiculous. French, unlike Italian or Spanish, obsoleted two subjunctive tenses, the imperfect and the pluperfect.

The fact is neither of them are spontaneously used in spoken or written form. This is not new. The decline started in the 18th century and in 1900, even the prescriptive French language education rulers had no choice but to accept their substitution by the present and past subjunctive by students.

Nowadays, when they are used orally, that's only to make jokes about how weird/funny they sound, *fusse*/*eusse* and some forms of *pouvoir* →  *pusse*, *savoir* →  *susse* and *voir* →  *visse*. In literature, these tenses are also extremely rare except a few third person singular, less "disruptive".

Native French readers do understand what is meant by *fusse pas avisé* in Camus text, but without precisely identifying the tense.

Real life French could have be:

> *C'était assez drôle que je ne m'en sois pas avisé plus tôt.*

or better, *s'aviser* being also rare:

> *C'était assez drôle que je ne n'en aie pas pris conscience plus tôt*.

The tense used by Camus was correctly identified by Lambie as the pluperfect subjunctive. Here the pronominal verbe *s'aviser* is used at the negative form:

> ***que je ne m'en fusse pas avisé plus tôt.***

It is worth noting that the verb *aviser* conjugated at the imperfect subjunctive in passive, negative mode is:

> ***que je n'en fusse pas avisé plus tôt.***

As you see, it's no surprise they can be confused with each other, even with the help of a grammar book.

Camus' fancy choice didn't make it to the English translation which uses a simpler phrasing and the past perfect:

> It struck me as rather odd that picture had escaped my memory until now.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "So my question is *why is the imperfect subjunctive used* in this quote from *L'Étranger*?"

[It is not the imperfect subjunctive, it is the pluperfect subjunctive.]

Sentence: « C'était assez drôle que je ne m'en fusse pas avisé plus tôt. »

**The grammatical reason for this:**

1. *C'est drôle* is considered a feeling (un sentiment). Things like: *C'est drôle* que or *C'est dommage* que or *C'est bien que* take the subjunctive in French. For example: **C'est drôle que tu le dise** ou **C'est drôle que tu l'aies dit**.
   Please see below. The verb in the subordinate clause is often in the past subjunctive.
2. 

> **Le subjonctif passé est souvent employé à la suite de différentes expressions courantes**.
> C'est dommage que tu n'aies pas pu avoir la
> chance de la rencontrer.
> C'est bien que tu aies réussi à la
> convaincre.
> Ça m'ennuie que tu ne sois pas encore arrivée.
> Je ne
> comprends pas que tu n'aies pas pris le temps de la visiter.
>
> [allo prof](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/le-subjonctif-passe-f1205)

**The Present Tense** in the main clause in the sample sentence with the past subjunctive in the second:
« **C'est** assez drôle que **je ne m'en sois pas avisé** plut tôt. »

So,  as regards the sequence of tenses rule (**concordance des temps**), if you put *C'est dommage* in the imperfect tense in French (translated into English as simple past) *C'était dommage que* [It was a shame or too bad]), **then the past subjunctive verb in the subordinate clause has to become pluperfect subjunctive.**

**The Imperfect Tense** in the main clause in the sample sentence with the pluperfect subjunctive in the second:

« **C'était** assez drôle que **je ne m'en fusse pas avisé** plus tôt. »

3.
This sequence-of-tenses rule is explained in this short, succinct tutorial from *Le Figaro:*

> Le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif est un temps surtout employé en
> littérature à la troisième personne du singulier et c'est là sa
> principale difficulté. Il permet d'exprimer une action incertaine en
> principe réalisée au moment où on parle.
>
> Je ne pensais pas qu'il eût terminé à temps.
>
> **Dans une phrase où la proposition principale est à l'imparfait de
> l'indicatif, on utilise le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif dans la
> subordonnée pour rester cohérent avec la concordance des temps.**

[Le Figaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/regle/conjugaison/plus-que-parfait_subjonctif.html)

[all bolding mine]

Comment: Vous avez bien décrit l'usage traditionnel de ce temps - concordance des temps au passé avec un subjonctif-. On aurait sans doute pu ajouter que les écrivains d'aujourd'hui ne l'utiliserait sans pas pour autant (ou rarement).

Answer (score 0):

There is no shift in meaning in the modern usage, it is the same as the usage made of it in days gone by. Besides, if it is not used in the spoken language, it is only rather rare in the witten one; it is not quite obsolete ([André Racicot : Au cœur du français](https://andreracicot.ca/imparfait/).

> D’ailleurs, le journaliste André Thérive y allait d’un commentaire lapidaire : seuls les écrivains prétentieux emploient encore le subjonctif imparfait[1]. Pourtant, il y en a encore beaucoup.
>
> [1] Cité par Grevisse et Goose, Le bon usage., p. 1157.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sub>¹ It is perhaps not superfluous to mention that even if this is a typical opinion, nevertheless, one should take it as opinion, keeping in mind such other comments as in the following part; the concern with preserving to the language a certain functionality is not to be dismissed entirely.</sub>
>
> **Bien des langagiers sont d’avis que l’imparfait du subjonctif est un mode obsolète. D’ailleurs, il a disparu de la langue courante et on peut penser que la plupart des francophones n’ont pas la moindre idée de la manière dont on le forme.**
>
> **L’imparfait du subjonctif survit**
> **Il survit, certes, mais tout juste.**

([réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_aventures_d_Arthur_Gordon_Pym/KIAWCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fusse+rappel%C3%A9%22&pg=PA193&printsec=frontcover)) frappant des mains, criant et faisant mille enfantillages semblables, jusqu'à ce que je fusse rappelé à moi-même et aux dernières limites du désespoir et de la misère humaine, en voyant tout à coup le navire nous présenter maintenant ...

([réf.2, 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Voyage_dans_l_Empire_de_Maroc/s1doDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fusse+dans%22&pg=PT27&printsec=frontcover)) On nous dit qu'il y avait des femmes, mais quoique je fusse dans le jardin, je ne les pus voir, parce qu'une autre haie en forme de paravent me dérobait toute la vue de l'intérieur. Je continuai donc ma promenade, entendant beaucoup de

([réf. 3, 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Y_a_t_il_du_wi_fi_dans_l_espace/4mubDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fusse+dans%22&pg=PT49&printsec=frontcover)) Je me rappelle avoir débouclé mon harnais et profité de ces premières sensations d'apesanteur, bien que je fusse dans l'espace confiné du Soyouz. Iouri sait parfaitement se faire comprendre sans dire un mot. Je n'ai jamais vu personne

([réf. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Promenades_et_escalades_dans_les_Pyr%C3%A9n/LMnuDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fusse+dans%22&pg=PT122&printsec=frontcover)) Quoique je fusse dans un repos parfait, j'étais essoufflé comme si j'avais exécuté le travail le plus fatigant. J'avais des pulsations fébriles, j'éprouvais quelque difficulté à élever la voix, et ressentais un malaise général.

([ref. 5, 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/S%C3%A9n%C3%A9chal_Volume_2/sPe7DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22comprisse%22&pg=PT356&printsec=frontcover)) Othon braillait des ordres sans que j'y comprisse rien. Roufos, qui tenait son étendard de la main gauche, levait de la droite sa hache d'arçon, bien au-dessus de l'épaule, menaçant les fretins qui s'agglutinaient à son flanc pis que

([ref. 6, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Outremer/3jTzgRzwka8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22comprisse%22&pg=PT13&printsec=frontcover)) Je le découvrais, le Brésil, comme au siècle seizième Pedro Alvarez Cabral : mais à travers ses mots, à maman, ses souvenirs qui me permettaient d'y voyager, quoique je ne comprisse pas grandchose encore à ce qu'elle disait, à quel espace de …

([ref. 7, 2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Un_%C3%A9t%C3%A9_en_Provence_R%C3%A9cits_et_chroniqu/qfwUAAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22prissent%22&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover)) En partant pour la guerre enEurope, James n'avait appris quedes ragotsà bord du liberty shipgarni de couchettes et tapissés au mal de mer. Les bruits les plus farfelus couraient, sans que les gradés prissent la peine de les démentir, ...

([ref. 8, 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cavalier_d_%C3%A9p%C3%A9e/DM1KEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22comprisse%22&pg=PT50&printsec=frontcover)) Jamais la mère de ma mère ne put dire un mot que je comprisse, et, à sa mort, je vis dans son cadavre la mort d'une étrangère, aussi silencieuse qu'elle l'avait été pour moi en vie, disparue hors de la cité habitable, et dont l'absence ...

([ref. 9, 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cornik_Consulting_%C3%A9pisode_3/IvWVDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22entendisse%22&printsec=frontcover)) Ça aurait pu être la dernière phrase que j'entendisse, et elle n'était pas fameuse.

([ref. 10, 1926](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Voyageur_sur_la_terre/WSb5Df_TuU8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22entendisse%22&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover)) Il était donc nécessaire qu'elle le vît seule, mais aussi que j'entendisse ce qu'il avait à lui dire.

[Déclin, Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_imparfait_en_fran%C3%A7ais#D%C3%A9clin)

Comment: Elle ne t'a pas intrigué, cette phrase: *la plupart des francophones n’ont pas la moindre idée ni de la manière dont on le forme* ?

Comment: @jlliagre « Ni » n'était pas dans la phrase et a été ajouté après (hacking) ou bien il y était parce que c'est de la copie, et alors il a été enlevé dans la page web parce que maintenant il n'y est plus.

Comment: Pas de hackers là dessous. *Ni* était bien présent dans la phrase originale que tu as recopiée. Je l'ai signalé à son auteur qui l'a corrigée. N'hésite pas à en faire de même.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça rassure.

Comment: Deux des dates que tu indiques sont fantaisistes, ou du moins sont celles de rééditions. Je serais plus que surpris que Baudelaire ait publié quelque chose en 2020 ou que quelqu'un qui est mort en 1928 ait publié en 2016...

Comment: "There is no particular meaning conferred to the modern usage". What does that mean?? Your first paragraph is quite confusing.

Comment: @Lambie I wanted to say that there has been no shift in meaning; I think that this way of putting it amounts more or less to the same thing.

Comment: Using this tense today has no particular meaning. The same usage is made of it today as in days gone by. **Although** not used in spoken language and also rather rare in  written French, it is not obsolete quite yet. //Is that what you meant? Just bear in mind, I had to read your rendition multiple times to understand it.

Comment: Ta référence n° 10 a été publiée en 1926, pas en 2014, la précédente fait un usage erroné de l'imparfait du subjonctif. *ça aurait pu être la dernière phrase que j'aie entendu*. L'auteur de la réf. n° 7 est né en 1817, difficile pour lui de publier 200 ans plus tard. Tu devrais faire plus attention à ce que tu cites.

Comment: @jlliagre (LBU : C'est quand le verbe principal  est au passé qu'il y a un usage propre à la langue écrite. Elle emploie l'imparfait quand le subjonctif exprime un fait qui
est simultané ou postérieur par rapport au verbe principal) « Ça aurait pu être » est un temps passé (conditionnel passé 1). Pourquoi y aurait-il une erreur ?